# Android Searchview not shown though keyboard is popped up

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have the code below for searchview implementation. I have written listener code for the searchview to dismiss a fragment, if it is visible. On tap of search icon, fragment gets dismissed correctly, but searchview does not show up,  keyboard gets popped up though. On tapping search icon again, serch textview comes.

Is there any obvious issue with the code below. Am I missing something?

Any help is much appreciated

```
mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    if (null != mSearchView) {
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    }

    mSearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            hideOverLayFragments();
        }
    });
```

Code for search menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.tcs.agilebiz.activities.HomeActivity">

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:checked="true"
    android:orderInCategory="103"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
    android:title="Search" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your SearchView like this

```
 MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
 mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but no luck with the above solution